# Use javascript to search page for link text

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="profile"]:contains("David")')
.closest('td').find('.fightMobster').click();
});
```

This searches the page content for the word 'David' and clicks the link.

I'm wanting to progress this. Instead of searching the page contents, I want to search for the LINK text.

For example, the link to 'David' might be http://www.example.com/164522

So I'd like to search the page for 164522 instead.

Also, I'd like to implement a form where you can specify the text you are searching for. Sort of a text box where you can type 164522 and a button which starts and stops to search process.

Comment: Do you mean that you'll have a link like `<a href="someLink">David</a>`?

Comment: @RobH That's correct mate :)

Comment: Then your current selector will work without the href restriction. i.e. `$('a:contains(David)')`

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should use

```js
$('a:contains(David)')
```